# rails 3 rack middleware issue , undefined method `each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rack, middleware

I want to print the body of template using rack middleware.below is my settings...

```
          #config/initializers/response_timer.rb
         class ResponseTimer
            def initialize(app)
                 @app = app
            end

            def call(env)
             status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
             [status, headers, response.body]
            end

         end  


       #application.rb file
       config.middleware.use "ResponseTimer"
```

when i made the request domainname/students/ i am getting below error.

```
              undefined method `each' for #<String:0xd69a2e0>
```

plz help.

Comment: If you have found a solution on your own, can you please answer your own question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solve my own problem by changing [status, headers, response.body] to [status, headers, [response.body]] , placing response.body inside array.